# Java post-increment (++) not behaving as expected when passed as a parameter

Tags: java, post-increment, pre-increment

I came across the following issue:

```
private void doStuff(int i) {
   if(i>10) {
      return;
   }
   doStuff(i++); 
}

public void publicMethod() {
   doStuff(i);
}
```

I would expect this to run `doStuff` 10 times and then return.

However `i++` does not get executed before the `doStuff` is called again with `0`.

Result is an infinite loop.  I know how to fix it but I am wondering if this behaviour is correct or a bug.

Comment: It is expected behaviour when you use post incrementation

Comment: ...and you will get what you expect if you use `doStuff(++i)` instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Now I would expect this to run doStuff 10 times and then return, however i++ does not get execute before the doStuff is called again with 0.

Yes, the result of the post-increment operator is the original value... and then inside the next call to the method you've a new `i`. So in other words, this call:

```
doStuff(i++);
```

is equivalent to:

```
int original = i;
i = original + 1;
doStuff(original);
```

From [JLS section 15.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2):

> The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable *before* the new value is stored.

Given that you don't use `i` again afterwards (and thus any side-effect on it is pointless), why not just simplify your life?

```
doStuff(i + 1);
```

(As with *all* parameters in Java, you're seeing pass-by-value - changing the value of `i` in the method does *not* change the value of the caller's argument.)

Comment: +1 or `doStuff(++i);` would work but is not as good an option.

Comment: Why is `i + 1` a better option than `++i`?  Readability?

Comment: @DavidGrant: Yes - you don't need to think about any ordering. The side-effect on the value of `i` is pointless, so why bother with it at all?

Comment: @JonSkeet "pass-by-reference"? Did you intend to say "pass-by-value"?

Answer (score 4):

It behaves as <strike>expected</strike> it should, you probably want to replace `i++` with `++i`.

Check the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) on how to use the prefix/postfix unary increment operator:

```
class PrePostDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = 3;
        i++;
        // prints 4
        System.out.println(i);
        ++i;               
        // prints 5
        System.out.println(i);
        // prints 6
        System.out.println(++i);
        // prints 6
        System.out.println(i++);
        // prints 7
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

(excerpt from the linked page)

Comment: Well as I wrote, I know how to fix it just like you pointed out ++i, but I am a bit surprised. I would have expected it to perform the operation first and then make the call.

Comment: @dngfng: It increments `i` before it makes the call, but the *argument* to the call is the original value of `i`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, indeed.. i've just fixed it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `++` operator works just as expected. it first returns the value of the variable, and then increases the variable, hence you always pass 0.

This:

```
doStuff(i++);
```

is like:

```
int x = i;
i += 1;
doStuff(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

`i++` means that: "use value of i and then increment it". It will always be zero when passed down. It is a value type, not a reference type. If that would be an object, that would be no problem because it would be handled as reference.