# Should I use ++x instead of x++ as method parameter in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to pass a number to a method by increasing its value +1 as shown below:

`setCounter(count++);`

However, the value is not increased and I think passing parameter as `setCounter(++count);` may be a better idea. However, there are some threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860070/java-post-increment-not-behaving-as-expected-when-passed-as-a-parameter) on SO and I am not sure what is the best option to pass a count value by increasing +1. Any idea?

Comment: They do different things. Do the one you mean.

Comment: The best course of action is _not to use either_, and increment `count` on a separate line before or after the call to `setCounter()`, depending on what you mean. This is the most clear in case you come back to the code in three months and forget why you did what you did.

Comment: @GaëlJ If it was my question, I did not asked and refer that question in my question.

Comment: The answer is in it though..

Comment: @Moderators You can close now, never mind :)))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`count++` --> return the value of count and then increment it
`++count` --> increment the value of count and then return it

In this case, second one is what you need to use.

Suppose `i = 3` 
Then `System.out.println(i++)` prints out `3`. 
`System.out.println(++i)` prints out `4`.

However, at the end in both of the implementations `i` becomes `4`.

Apart from all of that, I strongly believe incrementing the counter in one line above and then sending it to the function is more simplistic, expressive and readable solution.

Comment: Perfect explanations, thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically they are not the same.

If you use `count++` it will pass the count value and increment by one after the method call. But if you use `++count` it will increment the value first and pass the value after the increment.

when you put `System.out.print(counter);` it will print the same value. but it is not the same. So in when considering your code snippet, by changing it to

```
setCounter(++count);
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

count++ has the side-effect of changing the value of count in the current scope (global, class, function, etc.). If you are programming in a functional style, then simply pass count + 1 which will not have any side effect to any further code within your current context.

Also, when passing an argument, there is no difference between ++x or x++, as the expression (++x or x++) will be fully evaluated before calling setCounter().